# How to find Gaussian primes $10^6 < |\mathfrak{p}| < 2 \times 10^6$ with Pari-GP?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-software, computational-number-theory

I am looking through the PARI/GP [reference](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.13.0/refcard-nf.pdf) card.

Example, listing primes over $\mathbb{Z}$ is standard computer homework exercise [[1](https://primes.utm.edu/curios/index.php?start=6&stop=6)]:

- 100129
- 126691
- 193013
- 284933
- 492113
- 769591

How to write a program to find Gaussian prime numbers $\mathfrak{p} = a + bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $10^6 < |a|, |b| < 2 \times 10^6$ ?

---

Related:

- [Prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674814/prime-elements-in-mathbbz-sqrt2?rq=1)
- [Prime elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892800/prime-elements-of-mathbbzi-sqrt5)
- [Finding Gaussian Primes along Lines in $\mathbb Z[i]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351967/finding-gaussian-primes-along-lines-in-mathbb-zi?rq=1)

Comment: This quite old post on [Gaussian Primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33214/gaussian-primes) seems closely related.  It's focus is on using a sieve type algorithm analogous to Eratosthenes. Some background theory is rehearsed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4174961/a-method-for-factoring-integers-into-gaussian-factors) on factoring.

Comment: the exercise is to write the program listing the primes.  This could also be here https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you familiar with the characterization of Gaussian primes up to associates?  Is the use of Pari/GP (mentioned only in the title) important?

Comment: @hardmath Yes so I am specifying a programming language here...

Comment: In Gaussian integers, primes $p \equiv 3 \pmod4$ stay primes and primes $ p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ can be factored into $p=(a+bi)(a-bi)$ where $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ are Gaussian primes. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4175335/930909) for an algorithm to generate those Gaussian prime factors.

Comment: If you wish to avoid implementing the logic of primality over the Gaussian integers yourself (see this previous Question [Gaussian prime integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042569/gaussian-prime-integers), reducing that to primality of rational integers), then you should consult the `factor( )` function described under [Pari/GP Arithmetic functions](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Arithmetic_functions.html).  In the range you want, the distinction between proven primes and probable primes is not important.

Answer (score 1):

I will compute below the numbers $\mathfrak p=a+ib$ constrained to the following "triangle" restrictions:
$$ 10^6< b<a<2\cdot 10^6\ .$$
(From here build conjugates and associates to get also $\pm a\pm ib$ and $\pm b\pm ia$.)

In particular, $\mathfrak p\not\in\Bbb Z$, so $p:=\mathfrak p\bar{\mathfrak p}=a^2+b^2$ is a prime in $\Bbb Z$ which splits in two parts in the Gaussian integers. Here, $p$ is congruent to $1$ modulo four lying in the interval $J$ between $2\cdot 10^{12}$ and $8\cdot 10^{12}$.

One (slow) algorithm would take all these primes $p$ one by one, write them in the form $p=a^2+b^2$ and check the "triangle" condition. There are roughly some

```
? floor(intnum(x=2*10^12, 8*10^12, 1/log(x)))
%3 = 205708205954
```

primes in $J$, and half of them split in $\Bbb Z[i]$. A lot of primes for my taste. Below, there is an old fashioned pari/gp code implementing this slow algorithm. (It avoids the prime $1+i$, just in case somebody wants to relax $b<a$ to $b\le a$...)

The "real job" is done by the pari/gp factorization of Gaussian integers, a prime `p` in $\Bbb Z$ was slightly changed to `I*p` to implicitly tell pari/gp to factor over $\Bbb Z[i]$.

```
{f(N) = local(p, z, a, b, c, count);
count = 0;
forprime(p=2*N^2, 8*N^2,
    if( (p-3) % 4,
        z = factor(I*p)[1, 1];
        a = real(z); b = imag(z);
        if(a < b, c = a; a = b; b = c;);
        if( (N < b) && (a < 2*N), 
            z = a + I*b; count = count + 1;
            print(count, " --> ", z, " with norm ", p);)))}
```

Then `f(100)` delivers some $579$ such (normed) primes, and there is a quick end. The last ones are:

```
570 --> 190 + 189*I with norm 71821
571 --> 194 + 185*I with norm 71861
572 --> 195 + 184*I with norm 71881
573 --> 197 + 182*I with norm 71933
574 --> 195 + 188*I with norm 73369
575 --> 199 + 186*I with norm 74197
576 --> 196 + 191*I with norm 74897
577 --> 196 + 195*I with norm 76441
578 --> 199 + 194*I with norm 77237
579 --> 199 + 196*I with norm 78017
?
```

Seen from this perspective, this algorithm seems to be "better" than the brute force algorithm considering all $(a,b)$ with $100<b<a<200$, and testing for the primality of $a+ib$. At the cost of having a good primes generator for $\Bbb Z$.

I have also started...

```
? f(10^6)
1 --> 1000006 + 1000001*I with norm 2000014000037
2 --> 1000008 + 1000003*I with norm 2000022000073
3 --> 1000010 + 1000003*I with norm 2000026000109
4 --> 1000008 + 1000007*I with norm 2000030000113
5 --> 1000013 + 1000002*I with norm 2000030000173
6 --> 1000013 + 1000008*I with norm 2000042000233
7 --> 1000019 + 1000004*I with norm 2000046000377
8 --> 1000019 + 1000014*I with norm 2000066000557
9 --> 1000018 + 1000017*I with norm 2000070000613
10 --> 1000021 + 1000014*I with norm 2000070000637
11 --> 1000026 + 1000009*I with norm 2000070000757
12 --> 1000028 + 1000007*I with norm 2000070000833
13 --> 1000021 + 1000016*I with norm 2000074000697
14 --> 1000027 + 1000010*I with norm 2000074000829
```

and the primes are slowly printed one by one, as they are fished and tested for relevant...

Comment: I did some homework, I typed `factor(29, 1*I)` and it returned `[     -I 1]` and `[5 + 2*I 1]` and `[2 + 5*I 1]`.  So we learn that $\mathfrak{p} = 2 + 5i$ is a Gaussian prime.

Comment: OK let $\mathfrak{p} = 195 + 176i$ is prime and $\mathfrak{q} = 186 + 185i$ is prime and then $(p) + (q) = (1) = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ as [ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) which is to say $\text{GCD}(\mathfrak{p}, \mathfrak{q}) = 1$.  Working through the PARI/GP syntax, I have to look up `factor(I*p)[1,1]` and so forth.